# Scipy root-finding method

Tags: python, scipy

I am writing a class that has an mathematical function as an attribute, say *f*.

*f* is:

- Defined on a real segment [-w;+w]
- Positive and bounded above by a real H
- even (for all x in [-w;+w],  f(x)=f(-x)) and f(w)=f(-w)=0
- Differentiable over [-w;+w] and its derivative is positive and continuous over [-w;0]

My class looks like :

```
from scipy.misc import derivative
from scipy.integrate import quad
from math import cosh, sqrt

class Function(object):

    w = 1.
    PRECISION = 1e-6    

    def f(self, x):
        '''This is an example but f could be 
           any math function matching requirments above.
        '''
        return 0.5+1.07432*(1-cosh(x/1.07432)) 

    def deriv_f(self, x):
        return derivative(self.f, x, self.PRECISION)

    def x_to_arc_length(self, x):
        def func(x): 
            return sqrt(1+self.deriv_f(x)**2)
        return quad(func, -self.w, x)[0]

    def arc_length_to_x(self, L):
        bound = [-self.w, self.w]
        while bound[1]-bound[0] > self.PRECISION:
            mid= sum(bound)/2
            bound[(self.x_to_arc_length(mid)-L > 0)] = mid
        return sum(bound)/2
```

I use bisection to inverse the arc length method, but I was looking at changing this for one of the `scipy.optimize` root-finding method to gain speed. 
I am new to scipy and must admit that my math are a bit rusted...
Scipy gives me the choice between `brentq`, `brenh`, `ridder`, `bisect` and `newton`.

Could anyone point me to the best-suited method for a case like this ? Or maybe there is a better library for this ?

Comment: Try and find out? Set up trials for accuracy, set up trails for speed, and compare the various methods. Just be careful with premature optimization.

Comment: @Evert : To clarify, f is set as a catenary in the code of my question but could be set to any function matching the requirements. I can try a few functions but I was hoping there would be a mathematical approach to the issue. I amended the question to make it clear f is an example.

Comment: I know very little `python`, but in numerical analysis the Brent method is often suggested for root finding of a scalar function. And it looks like the  `scipy` tutorial goes along with [this suggestion](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/tutorial/optimize.html) (search for "root finding" in the linked page). Newton's method may be faster in selected cases, but it's usually more prone to breaking down. Rememeber that for all these methods, except for Newton, you need to provide in input the extremes of a interval where `f` changes sign.

Comment: Thanks DeltalV, I believe that's the answer to my question. I found this description on Wolfram.mathworld: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrentsMethod.html. That looks much better than a simple bisection ! `brenth` is an hyperbolic version of the quadratic `brentq`. It seems they are on a par (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brenth.html#scipy.optimize.brenth). Is it worth benchmarking it or shall I stick to `brentq` ?

Comment: the `scipy` doc you linked states that `brenth` is "Generally on a par with the brent routine, but not as heavily tested."  Given this fact, you may just want to go with `brentq`. On the other hand, I wouldn't expect benchmarking a root finding method to take a lot of your time, so it may be worth the hassle just to get a bit of practice with this kind of methods. It's up to you, and to the time you have available for this.

Comment: I wouldn't expect the two methods to show major differences, though...

Comment: @DeltaIV : Many thanks. I'll see if I have time to look into this as these methods are not crucial for now and a lot still needs to be done... Why wouldn't you post your comments as an answer so that I could accept it ?

Comment: You say f is positive, but then you say f(0) = 0 and f' is positive on the negative side of the domain. This doesn't seem consistent.

Comment: Oh, whoops. Never mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not an expert at Python, but I know from Numerical Analysis that among the methods you listed (Brent, bisection, Ridder's method and Newton-Raphson), Brent's method is usually preferred for generic real scalar functions *f* of a single real variable *x*. As you can read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brent%27s_method), if *f* is continuous and the method is applied to an interval [a,b] with *f(a)f(b)*<0, then Brent's method enjoys guaranteed convergence to a zero, like the bisection method. For many well-behaved functions, Brent's method converges much faster than bisection , but in some unlucky cases it can require *N^2* iterations, where *N* is the number of iterations of bisection to achieve a given tolerance.

[Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Proof_of_quadratic_convergence_for_Newton.27s_iterative_method), on the other hand, usually converges faster than Brent's, when it converges, but there are cases where it doesn't converge at all. For the same function, Newton's method may or may not converge, depending also on the distance between the starting point and the root. Thus, it's riskier to use in a general purpose code.

Regarding the choice between `brentq` and `brenth`, [it looks like](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brenth.html) they should be pretty similar, with the first one more heavily tested. Thus you could go for `brentq`, or, if you have some time, do a little benchmarking between them.

Comment: I can confirm this has been my experience so far. I haven't tested Newton enough against Brent, but Brent seems quick enough and converges.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the answer by DeltaIV, I did a benchmark of the different options based on the example above.

```
 2000    0.005    0.000   10.395    0.005 diff.py:42(arc_length_to_x_newton)
 2000    0.005    0.000   16.842    0.008 diff.py:36(arc_length_to_x_brenth)
 2000    0.005    0.000   17.141    0.009 diff.py:30(arc_length_to_x_brentq)
 2000    0.005    0.000   26.375    0.013 diff.py:48(arc_length_to_x_ridder)
 2000    0.005    0.000   72.249    0.036 diff.py:54(arc_length_to_x_bisect)
```

It seems that in this case Newton method is the fastest, probably because the function is well-behaved (i.e. continuous and even derivative bounded below by 1).

The risks of non convergence (stationary points, cycles or derivative issues) do not apply to the functions described above, so I finally went for `newton`.